# how define a serial port in a class in python

Tags: python, class, serial-port

Keep getting error that serial port is not defined when I try to add the definition of the serial port inside a class. When I do it outside a class, all works well.

tried using with and without self definition, and with or without `__init__` And in `__init__` . I tried to chance to `def __init__ (self, ser)`

```
class sensor():
    class DP_sensor():
        def __init__(self):
        # definitions for USB0 serial for dust particle sensor
            self.ser = serial.Serial()
            #ser.port = sys.argv[1]
            self.ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
            self.ser.baudrate = 9600
            self.ser.open()
            self.ser.flushInput()
        def dp_process_frame(d):
            r = struct.unpack('<HHxxBBB', d[2:])
            pm25 = r[0]/10.0
            pm10 = r[1]/10.0
            checksum = sum(v for v in d[2:8])%256
            print("PM 2.5: {} μg/m^3  PM 10: {} μg/m^3 CRC={}".format(pm25, pm10, "OK" if (checksum==r[2] and r[3]==0xab) else "NOK"))
        def dp_sensor_read():
            byte = 0x0
            while byte != b'\xaa':
                byte = self.ser.read(size=1)
            d = self.ser.read(size=10)
            if d[0] == 0xc0:
                dp_process_frame(byte + d)
```

I looked at other examples and I seem to do the right thing. This is the error I keep getting

> File "/home/pi/AirQuality/AirQual_v03classes.py", line 71, in
>   dp_sensor_read
>       self.ser.write(b) NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You are not referring the `self` in the method definition. Use `dp_process_frame(self, d):`  and `dp_sensor_read(self)`

Comment: where is that error on your code? cant find self.ser.write(b)

Comment: Please read an introduction to classes in Python. All instance methods need to take `self` as their first parameter. And please title your question appropriately: this doesn't have anything to do with serial ports, it's just a question about classes. Also, why do you have a nested class?

Comment: @@Daniel Roseman...because there a different types of sensors, each with their own methods


@han Solo
But then I also need to add that as parameter when I call the method?

Comment: @han solo

But then what do I add when I call the metho from main? I'm trying to figure this out, but books aren't to clear

Comment: @wonka, thats a typre error when I copies it, should be read instead of write

Comment: @han solo
if I do that, I get the error

    dp.dp_sensor_wake()
TypeError: dp_sensor_wake() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

yet if I look at the documentations, self does not have to be provided according examples I see

Comment: and when I do give it a name (as I saw in another example, I get this error


    dp = sensor.DP_sensor("dust_particles")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Reinier: ***`TypeError:`***:  Wher do you want the parameter `"dust_particles"` to be assigned to? You have only: `def __init__(self):` and `self` ist reserved for Python magic reference passing. Take the tour at: [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: all problems were gone after I added the USB port in the init call. Don't understand, but it works now

        def __init__(self,USB_port):
        # definitions for USB0 serial for dust particle sensor
            self.ser = serial.Serial()
            #ser.port = sys.argv[1]
            self.ser.port = USB_port
            self.ser.baudrate = 9600
            self.ser.open()
            self.ser.flushInput()

Comment: @Reinier then each function of class should have self in params def dp_sensor_read(self):